# Typscript array.find() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an angular-service that returns array of guids in the form of 18 digit number (EX:`281586874019181108`) and I am trying to compare it with existing-array of such numbers
Sometimes (4 out of 10) array.find() fails saying `Order Does Not Exists` even when there is a matching value. I found a couple of questions, but those didn't seem to address my problem.
I am having a hard time debugging in chrome since in network-tab it shows different values in "Preview" and "Response" sections of request

```
this.http.get("some/url").subscribe(orders => {
        for(const order of orders) {
            let found = order.dispatchOrderGuid
                ? this.exixstingOrders.find(existingOrder => existingOrder.dispatchOrderGuid=== order.dispatchOrderGuid)
                : this.exixstingOrders.find(existingOrder => existingOrder.dispatchOrderId=== order.dispatchOrderId)

            if (found) {
              console.log("Order Exists");
            } else {
              console.log("Order Does Not Exists");
            }
        }
});
```

[image: Response tab]
[image: Preview tab]

Thank you

Comment: Just eyeballing it your guid's appear to be numbers, and they appear to be bigger than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. Use strings.

Comment: How are you searching with `order.guid` when your response contain `dispatchOrderGuid`  as properties?

Comment: @JaredSmith, Why do I see different values in console. could you please help me with that part?

Comment: @KedarUdupa: Please correct `const found = order.guid` as well. Lets not worry about code length. we cant debug the issue if you are changing the provided code itself :)

Comment: @KedarUdupa: It should not display different value. The value comes from server.

Comment: The preview may be truncating the value so that it fits into a `Number` since your JSON values are out of range.

Comment: Try to parse your data before your loop maybe.

let stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(orders);

orders = JSON.parse(stringifiedData);

Comment: @ALourenço completely irrelevant, the OP's problem is using numbers bigger than what a Javascript number will hold.

Comment: @JaredSmith You sure stringify will not transform it into a string?

Comment: @ALourenço yes, numbers, even numbers bigger than Javascript can handle, are valid JSON. Stringifying and re-parsing will not convert them to strings. OP will have to convert them to string representation server-side.